# How to supply credentials to the V3 AWS-SDK on an AWS NodeJS Lambda to another AWS account

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

My application is an AWS Lambda which uses v3 of the AWS-SDK.

The purpose of my Lambda is to read from a DynamoDB table which holds the AWS secret key and access key of a customer, I then want to use the AWS-SDK to call the describeVpcs with the information retrieved from DynamoDB.

I can see the use of passing the access key and secret key into the `AWS.config.update` as been deprecated.

My code below will gather information about the VPCs in my AWS account rather than the customers. I am looking for the alteration needed to use the customers information.

```
const { EC2 } = require('@aws-sdk/client-ec2');

const ec2 = new EC2();

const describeVpcs = async () => {
  const params = {
  };

  try {
    const data = await ec2.describeVpcs(params);
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    throw new Error(e);
  }
};

module.exports = { describeVpcs };
```

Answer (score 1):

For your Lambda to have access to `describeVpcs`, you will need your lambda to assume a role in the other account. Basically, you need to create a role in the other account with the needed access, and you allow your Lambda to assume said role. You could follow this tutorial: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/

Answer (score 0):

you can try pass credentials like:

```
const ec2 = new EC2({credentials:{accessKeyId:'key',secretAccessKey:'secret'}});
```